# How to have HTML tags inside a jinja expression?

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have a variable `test` and it's value is `Asia is the largest continent in the world`

and in variable `cname` has value as `Asia` ,

Here I am trying to Bold the value `Asia` as below :

```
{{ test.replace(cname,<strong>cname</strong>) }}
```

But this gives me an error as, `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '<'`

required Output : **Asia** is the largest continent in the world

Is there a possible way to achieve this , any guiding links are much helpful , TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.format()` and use `|safe` filter to mark the string as safe. Without the `|safe` filter, HTML tags will be escaped, and appear "as is" on the rendered page.

```
{{ test.replace(cname,"<strong>{}</strong>".format(cname)) | safe }}
```

Comment: this gives me , `<strong>Asia</strong> is the largest continent in the world` , but the thing is i want Asia in the o/p as bold .....

Comment: What do you mean by "o/p"?

Comment: oh sorry , output (o/p)

Comment: But using `<strong>` tag is how you bold a text span in HTML. Do you mean you want to bold the text in Python console?

Comment: yeah , I am trying to bold the text , for this we generally use a strong tag , but jinja doesn't allow to use html tags with in an expression

Comment: Have you tested this? If you render this template and open in a web browser, it will appear bolded.

Comment: Yeah i have tested it shows me the <strong>Asia<strong>...... as a string

Comment: I see. You have the automatic HTML escaping on. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: perfect mate, I am checking the same in docs , could you please navigate me through the same?

Comment: Here is the part of the doc about auto escaping. [link](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#working-with-automatic-escaping).